# PageMethods not defined despite copying example code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On another forum someone complained that PageMethods are not defined. And someone provided an answer that said ... 'look, this is how you get them to work'. So I copied their code and tried it. I am still seeing PageMethods not defined.

The page looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PageMethods.aspx.cs" Inherits="PageMethods" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body onload="GetFromServer();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div>

</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetFromServer()
{
PageMethods.GetHello(OnGetHelloComplete);
}
function OnGetHelloComplete(result, userContext, methodName)
{
alert("Result: " + result + "\n" +
"Context: " + userContext + "\n" +
"Method name: " + methodName);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the code behind.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
public partial class PageMethods : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static string GetHello()
{
    return "Hello From Server!";
}
}
```

When you run the page a javascript error occurs - 'PageMethods' is not defined.

This is a .net 2.0 web site.

Comment: Similar to one I answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791811/pure-javascript-ajax-call-asp-net-webmethod/12791981

Comment: .NET 2.0, you say? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods.aspx), it looks like what you want to do is in .NET 3.5+.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will need .NET 3.5. I just used your exact code in a quick demo, and I was able to call the `GetHello` method without any trouble.